# How to change icon associated with a file-extension in Dired and all-the-icons?

Tags: dired, image-dired, icons

I use `dired` with ([all-the-icons-dired](https://github.com/jtbm37/all-the-icons-dired) which uses [all-the-icons](https://melpa.org/#/all-the-icons)).

**Current State**:
`.m` file presented with apple logo.
[image]

**Goal**: Change (override) icon of `.m` file to same as icon of `.matlab` file extension.

**What I've tried So far**:  from `all-the-icons-dired`'s README:

> [Each file face is already predefined by all-the-icons](https://github.com/jtbm37/all-the-icons-dired/blob/master/README.org#file-face)

So I try to add matlab logo with `.m` file in the `all-the-icons-data/file-icon-alist` variable. with

```
(use-package all-the-icons
    :config
    (add-to-list 'all-the-icons-data/file-icon-alist '("m" . ""))   ;;  is the matlab icon
  )
(use-package all-the-icons-dired)
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'all-the-icons-dired-mode)
```

However, There is still no change.

- Do you know what I'm doing wrong here?
- Should change another different variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `all-the-icons-data/file-icon-alist` was the just a pool of icons that `all-the-icons-extension-icon-alist` variables takes values. So I changed from `("m"  ... "apple")` to `("m" ... "matlab")` in `all-the-icons-extension-icon-alist` as like below:

```
(use-package all-the-icons
  :config
  (add-to-list 'all-the-icons-extension-icon-alist '("m"  all-the-icons-fileicon "matlab"  :face all-the-icons-orange))
  )
(use-package all-the-icons-dired)
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'all-the-icons-dired-mode)
```